# WPF Write/Read BitmapImage to XML failing with 'No imaging component.....' Error

Tags: wpf, xmlreader, bitmapimage, xmlwriter

I am trying to write/read a BitmapImage to Xml using the XmlReader/XmlWriter classes. On writing out I can see a nice long CDATA section in the output Xml file. When reading in I can see that it is indeed reading in that same CDATA section data. But the attempt to recreate the BitmapImage is failing with the error...

```
"No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found."
```

...on the line that says 'image.StreamSource = stream' below...

```
Public Sub WriteXmlImage(ByVal writer As XmlWriter, ByVal image as BitmapImage)
  Using stream As New MemoryStream
    Dim encoder = New PngBitmapEncoder
      encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image))
      encoder.Save(stream)
      writer.WriteCData(Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray()))
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function ReadXmlImage(ByVal reader As XmlReader) As BitmapImage
  Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(reader.Value))
    Dim image As New BitmapImage
    image.BeginInit()
    image.StreamSource = stream
    image.EndInit()
    return image
  End Using
End Sub
```

In testing I use the following trivial code to create a test BitmapImage...

```
Dim image As New BitmapImage(New Uri("c:\devil.png"))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried your code and it's working fine, except for the part that the `MemoryStream` that you're setting as `StreamSource` for the `BitmapImage` is disposed of by the using statement.

Comment: Thats great that it works for you. But that does not help me solve the problem! As it does not work for me.

Comment: What I meant was that the code you posted probably isn't the problem but I think you understood that.. Maybe this link will help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/wpf/thread/c28ebaa5-862f-4332-a5b3-8d7032bc24da.

Comment: Found the problem. Turns out to be my fault with a coding error that had nothing to do with the above source. Once I fixed that the above code worked just fine. Thanks anyway.